# postgresql: use timestamp variable within pl pgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Im new using pl pgsql. I want to concatenate two variables but im gotting always same error: time_ variable is not known

Let's say that date_ is of type date and time_ is of type time. The error came from this row:

```
sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.end, gs.date_+time_) - greatest(s.beg, gs.date_))) / 60) as Timing
```

My code is below

```
delcare 
  time_ time;
Begin
   execute $$SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time FROM $$||result_table INTO time_;
   execute $$SELECT MAX(date_) FROM $$||result_table INTO max_date;
   IF max_date is not NULL THEN
       execute $$DELETE FROM $$||result_table||$$ WHERE date_ >= $$||quote_literal(max_date);
   ELSE
       max_date := 'XXXXXXX';
   end if;
   execute $$
   INSERT INTO $$result_table$$
   (Id, gs.date_, TIME, timing)
   SELECT * from (
      select
      Id, gs.date_,
      (case
      When TRIM(set) ~ '^OPT[0-9]{3}/MINUTE/$'
      Then 'minute'
      When TRIM(set) ~ '^OPT[0-9]{3}/SECOND/$'
      Then 'second' as TIME, 
       
       sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.end, gs.date_+time_) -
                   greatest(s.beg, gs.date_)
                  )
      ) / 60) as Timing
  from source s cross join lateral
  generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day',
       least(s.end,
             CASE WHEN $$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$ = 'XXXXXXX'
             THEN (current_date)
             ELSE $$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$
             END)
   ), interval '1 day') gs(date_)
 where ( (beg, end) overlaps ($$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$'00:00:00', $$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$'23:59:59'))
 group by id, gs.date_, TIME
 ) as X
 where ($$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$ = X.date_  and $$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$ != 'XXXXXXX')
 OR  ($$||quote_literal(max_date)||$$ ='XXXXXXX')
```

Comment: `execute $$SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::time FROM $$||result_table INTO time_;` can be simplified to `time_ := localtime;`

Comment: yes @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. But it doesn't resolve the problem. :/

Comment: Asking the same question over again with the same impenetrable code again won't make the question better. This error message does not exist in the PostgreSQL code base.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL should be generated through `format()` and parameters should not be passed as string literals, but through placeholders and `using`.

Your code is really hard to read, incomplete and there are some substantial syntax errors which stem from e.g. a missing `END` for the CASE and parentheses not properly paired. So the following code might still contain some errors as I apparently have no way of testing it.

But as your main SELECT does not seem to use dynamic SQL at all, all the `quote_literal()` and string concatenation is unnecessary, just use the variables directly.

As max_date is supposed to be a `date` value you can assign the string `'XXXXX'` to it, but if you use the max_date directly, you can get rid of that check as far as I can tell.

```
declare 
  time_ time;
  max_date date;
  result_table text := 'contract_frequency';
  table_schema text := 'public';
Begin
   time_ := localtime; 
   execute format('SELECT MAX(date_) FROM %I.%I', table_schema, result_table) into INTO max_date;
   
   IF max_date is not NULL THEN
     execute format('DELETE FROM %I.%I WHERE date_ >= $1', table_schema, result_table) using max_date;
   ELSE
     -- you replace XXXX with current_date in the CASE expression 
     -- later on, so using current_date here seems the right thing to do
     max_date := current_date;
   end if;

   SELECT * 
   from (
      select
      Id, gs.date_,
      case 
        When TRIM(set) ~ '^OPT[0-9]{3}/MINUTE/$' Then 'minute'
        When TRIM(set) ~ '^OPT[0-9]{3}/SECOND/$' Then 'second' as TIME, 
      end
      sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.end, gs.date_+time_) - greatest(s.beg, gs.date_) ) ) / 60) as Timing
    from source s 
    cross join lateral 
      generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day', least(s.end, max_date)), interval '1 day') gs(date_)
    where (beg, end) overlaps (max_date::timestamp, max_date + time '23:59:59') 
    group by id, gs.date_, TIME
  ) as X
  where (max_date = X.date_ and max_date <> current_date)
    OR  (max_date = current_date)

end;
```

Comment: I'm really grateful . And with your proposal how to declare the table name ? Before i did result_table regclass := $$public.contract$$||frequency; . Thank you again @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @biwia: just declare it as a `text` variable. But if you need to include the schema, you need to split it up. See my edit

Comment: yes i see thank you . My variable frequency is a parameter of the plpgsql proc. It is passed directly . You see what i mean ? Thank you

Comment: @biwia: you should have shown your complete procedure and mentioned what is a parameter and what is not. Just pass the table name as a `text` parameter  then.

Comment: thank you for all your help. Just last little thing i have also in my code insert queries like updated in the original code. How should i modify it ? have an idea? Thank youu .

Comment: Same approach: identifiers should be included in the string using `format()` and `%I`. Parameters use parameter placeholders (`$1, $2, ...`)  and should be passed with the `USING` clause of the EXECUTE command.