# Replace the execute$$ with plpgsql format

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

Im using pl pgsql to create function, i was unable to transforom my insert query as written below to format dynamic-sql, i tried for two days and didn't got it. It's my first pub here Can anyone help please?

Thank you,

** My Code Is**

```
execute $$
  INSERT INTO $$result_table$$
  (Id, ts.date_, flo_nbr, duration)
  SELECT * from (
     select
     Id, ts.date_,
    (case
     When TRIM(set) ~ '^H[0-9]{1}/FLO0R0/$'
     Then 'FLO0R0'
     When TRIM(set) ~ '^H[0-9]{1}/FLOOR1/$'
     Then 'FLOOR1'
     end) as flo_nbr,
     sum(extract(epoch from (least(s.end, ts.date_+time_) -
           greatest(s.beg, ts.date_)
          )
    )) as duration
   from source s cross join lateral
   generate_series(date_trunc('day', s.beg), date_trunc('day',
     least(s.end,
     CASE WHEN $$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$ = '2012-01-01'
     THEN (current_date)
     ELSE $$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$
     END)
    ), interval '1 day') ts(date_)
    where ( (beg, end) overlaps ($$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$'00:00:00',      $$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$'23:59:59'))
    group by id, ts.date_, flo_nbr
    ) as temp
where ($$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$ = temp.date_  and 
$$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$ != '2012-01-01')
OR  ($$||quote_literal(date_construction)||$$ ='2012-01-01')
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are not the same person as @biwia? This looks too similar to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66024848/6464308) to be a coincidence.

Comment: No @LaurenzAlbe but i will read what he posts.

Comment: Without plpgsql, how should your INSERT-SELECT-statement look like? When that part is working, just replace the WHERE conditions with dynamic items. And do yourself a favour and start using the EXECUTE ... USING() statement. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: Why are you registering a new user for every new question?

Answer (score 1):

I won't translate this impenetrable piece of, er, code for you, but I will show you the ropes.

Instead of

```
EXECUTE $$INSERT INTO $$ || result_table || $$ (...)
          SELECT ... FROM ...
          WHERE $$ || quote_literal(date_construction) || $$ = '2012-01-01'$$;
```

you would write

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      $$INSERT INTO %I (...)
        SELECT ... FROM ...
        WHERE %L = '2012-01-01'$$,
      result_table,
      date_construction
   );
```

`%I` will format the argument as an SQL identifier, that is, surround it with double quotes if necessary, and `%L` will format the argument as a string literal, that is, properly quoted with single quotes.

Even better is to use the `USING` clause for parameters, as here:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      $$INSERT INTO %I (...)
        SELECT ... FROM ...
        WHERE $1 = '2012-01-01'$$,
      result_table,
   )
   USING date_construction;
```

Note that you cannot use parameters for identifiers, so you will have to stick to `format` for those.

The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Ok, thank you, its more clear now . My problem is how to use the select inside the insert? You see what i mean ? Can you please add a little blank case that i can understand it . kindly

Comment: The comparison of the date would probably be better with `execute format( ... where $1 = $2') using date_construction, date '2012-01-01'`

Comment: dsp, I tried to flesh out the example a little bit. Having `SELECT` and other constructs in the SQL statement won't make a difference. @FrankHeikens comment to your question is golden advice: first try to get that monster to run by just replacing the placeholders with values, and once you are sure it works as you want it to, convert it into dynamic SQL with placeholders.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If those dates are variable, yes. If they are constants, it would make more sense to have them as part of the string literal.